# Sorting arrays of objects

Tags: c++, oop, sorting

```
class Medicine{
protected:
    int id;
    int stock;
    string name;
    int concentration;
public:
    Medicine(); 
    Medicine(int id,int s,const string n,int c);        
    Medicine(const Medicine& m);                
    Medicine& operator=(const Medicine& m);     
    virtual ~Medicine();    
        int getStock() const;   
    int getConcentration() const;};
```

module 1

```
    template<typename T> class Vector
    {
    private:
        T* Elems;
        int Size;
        int Capacity;

    public:
        Vector()
    ~Vector()
    void add(T e)
    void remove(int pos)
    int getSize() const
    int getCapacity() const
    T get(int pos) const;}

template <typename T>
    T Vector<T>::get(int pos) const
    {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= this->getSize())
            return NULL;
        return this->Elems[pos];
    }
```

module 2

```
class MedRepo :
public:~MedRepo();
 void addMed(Medicine s);
     void upgrade(Medicine s);
Medicine* findById(int medId) ;
virtual void removeMed(int id) ;
int getNrMeds();
Vector<Medicine*> getAll() ;
protected:
    Vector<Medicine*> MedList;
};
```

module 3

```
typedef int (*comparefunction)(const void*, const void*);

int compareSA(const Medicine* e1, const Medicine* e2){
    int q1 = (*(Medicine **) e1)->getStock();
    int q2 = (*(Medicine **) e2)->getStock();

    if (q1 < q2){
             return -1;
         }
    else{
        if (q1>q2){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

module 4

So,this is a part of my code and what I want to do is to sort my objects with respect to some criterias,one of them is the one in the 4th module.I've been working with classes starting from this week and I've found some similar questions but I didn't understood the whole process about sorting.I've just read something about `std:sort` and `std::stable_sort` but I don't know how to use them for my data.All I have for now is:

```
Vector<Medicine*>* Control::sortByStockAsc(){
    Vector<Medicine*> all =repo->getAll();
```

Any ideas,suggestions,help?

Comment: Don't tell me this code actually works...

Comment: In the sense that I have no error/bug till now,yes

Comment: @MrMime As I said below, there have to be bugs simply by the type of the members you use. Not to mention that destructor, copy-constructor and assignment operator for `Medicine` are almost certainly pointless.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I see dozens of errors... That code will not compile, not in a million years... Are you SURE that this is your actual code?

Comment: @pmr I agree that they are useless for this example but the problem is more complex and I use them in other functions which doesn't affect my current issue

Comment: You don't have any dynamically allocated members in `Medicine`, the compiler will generate perfectly good assignment operator and copy constructor, destructor is not needed in that case as well. What troubles is the fact you claim that code works, when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

First: throw away your own `vector` class (it has bugs that are
obvious by looking at the type of the members). Use `std::vector<T>`.

If you really want to keep using it **and** want to use `std::sort`,
you will need to implement iterators for it. Given that you just
started with C++, this can be a real challenge (there are a lot of articles, whole helper-libraries, and book chapters devoted to it).

If you don't want to use `std::sort` and want to keep your own
`Vector`, implement a sorting algorithm for your container.

The ideal case: implement `operator<(const Medicine&, const
Medicine&)` for Medicine as a strict weak ordering relation and use it
like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<Medicine> mv;
std::sort(begin(mv), end(mv));
```

If there are more possibilities to compare Medicine, implement functors or free functions:

```
struct LessCmpMedicineByName {
  bool operator()(const Medicine&, const Medicine&) const;
};
struct LessCmpMedicineById {
  bool operator()(const Medicine&, const Medicine&) const;
};

// use
std::sort(begin(mv), end(mv), LessCmpMedicineByName());
// or with a lambda
std::sort(begin(mv), end(mv), [](const Medicine& x, const Medicine& y) {
  // comparison code here
  return true;
});
```

Comment: The teacher used that `Vector` class in all his examples and I took it from there.If I implement that operator,that will work only for one case,right?I need to do 1 ascending and one descending sort for 2 different arguments of the `Medicine` class.So,i'll have to implement `operator>` too,right?Also,how does `sort()` knows when to use > or < ?

Comment: @MrMime Tell you teacher, that `int` wont be sufficient. He is looking for `size_t`. He also shouldn't store the end as a size but as a pointer behind the end. If you implement both operators and want to choose between them, you need to tell `std::sort` about it by passing the right comparator as the third argument. `std::sort(begin, end, std::less<Medicine>)` or `std::sort(begin, end, std::greater<Medicine>)`. Or, again, use lambdas.

Comment: OK,it's the first time i hear the 'functors' term and I have no idea how lambdas work.The implementation for `operator<` could be something like what I have in the 4th module?Also,your `std::sort(begin(mv), end(mv), [](const Medicine& x, const Medicine& y)` is a lambda and I don't have to implement it for my sort to work,right?

Comment: @MrMime Please use the stackoverflow search function "[c++] functor" and "[c++] lambda" should answer this much better than any comment ever could.

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw away vector. There are many advantages to making your own containers. You must define your sorting criteria carefully for any sorting algorithm to work.

Any sorting operation needs just a > operator to work  your criteria must have the following properties:

```
for any a b and c, if a > b and b > c then it must be that a > c

for any a, a > a must be false.
```

equality is defined as:

```
(!(a > b ) && !( b > a ))
```

The equality condition can ( and should ) be coded into your sort algorithm. You don't need to specifically define an equality operator for your sorting criteria.

A regular sorting algorithm is not required to preserve the order of your inputs if they are equal. In a stable sorting algorithm, any input that are equal in the input must be emitted in the same relative order in the output. E.g. if you were sorting playing cards by number only and your input was 5h 4d 5s the output of a stable sort would have to be 4d 5h 
5s. For a non-stable sort it could output 4d 5s 5h.

Stable sorting is a little slower. You don't often need a stable sort.

Comment: What is the advantage of making your own container if you do it wrong?